# Angular template complains c_r1.getCatType is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, templates

I have a class in my angular (version 9.1.0) project like this:

```
export class Contract {
    contractName: string;
    limit: number;
    public getCatType(): string{
       if(this.limit > 0) return 'p';  
       return 'n';  // this is simplified code
    }
}
```

And I used it in the template:

```
      <tr *ngFor="let c of contracts">          
          <td>{{c.contractName}}</td>
          <td>{{c.limit | number}}</td>
          <td>{{c.getCatType()}}</td>
      </tr>
```

But the template complains ***c_r1.getCatType is not a function*** when it is running.

After investigation, I found that the contracts comes from the result of an API call and cause this issue:

```
    this.cService.getList(pId).subscribe((contracts: Contract[]) => {
        this.contracts = contracts;   // I guess this line cause the issue
    }, (err) => {...});
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Here is the inline demo for this error:
http://www.justa999.com/angular/#/cascade

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `Contract ` class is not a component, you have to write `getCatType` in your template component itself

Comment: contracts is an array, how can I write a method on component?

Comment: Can you provide an example of this behaviour, e.g. on jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/gde3rvq4/ Without it it's very hard to reason about what you're missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is not a good idea to use method on template in Angular. As this method will be called many times whenever angular runs the change detection cycle.

Secondly, you can use pipe instead of a direct method. Create a custom pipe add this logic in the transform method and use it.

Thirdly, 'c' doesn't have a method on it thats why angular is throwing an error, instead use this or whatever parameter you want to pass and return a result using this method:

```
<td>{{getCatType(c)}}</td>
```

Also, check where are you setting up the limit though it won't change how getCatType is being called on template.

For more details on pipe check out [this](https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp).